# Symfony2 : getting 2 table data in form and creating a contact us form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am working on Symfony,
I am facing a problem I have 2 table:

1. Contact (fk category_id)
2. Category

I want to create a form to display options to the users to select the category, enter some details and then submit.

But I don't no know how to combine 2 entity in one form and create a form.

I had created all the code from commend tools

Please help me or update me show I can share the full files.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples below are in full so study them and use whichever fits in your needs. You can modify as you wish. Because they are a bit long, I haven't read all of it but what I can say is, they give you an idea which way to go when dealing multiple forms in a single form.

**Example 1:**

[Full webform style CRUD example with an embedded associated entity in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony) uses "embedded entity" style form builder where parent entity is given as selecbox.

**Example 2:**

[Creating a combined formtype by embedding individual formtypes for one-to-many association in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/a4hv/creating-a-combined-formtype-by-embedding-individual-formtypes-for-one-to-many-association-in-symfony) combines two individual form types into one.

**Example 3:**

[Many-to-many association example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/toza/many-to-many-association-example-in-symfony) uses entity mapping in form builder and I think this would give you more flexibility to show what field you want to use in your form.